# Active directory account logging in from an unknown application or service

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, login

I have a 2008 R2 AD domain, where there are repeated attempts to login by a user is no longer here. The password has been changed, so the failed attempts are expected, but what I don't know is where that account is trying to log in from. I know the name of the host from which the login attempt is coming, and I believe that it is a result of the user's account name being embedded in some application, which should have used the system account instead, but that is history.

What I am looking for is a way to scan the host in order to find the source of the login requests. They happen in groups and with frequency, so it is easy for me to locate the event in logs.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

SysMon should be able to surface this information, including the executable image and parent image.  It would be recorded as an event Id 1, ProcessCreate.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/sysmon

Comment: SysMon should definitely help determine the process.  As pure speculation, I'd bet that the login attempts are from a service or scheduled task. To check the services: Open services.msc and look for anything that has the user's name in the "Log On As" field. Stop that service and give it updated credentials if you want it to continue to run. Otherwise, disable it. Most user generated scheduled tasks will show up under "Task Scheduler Library" in Task Scheduler.